# Dibujar cuadrados alineados en fila

Tags: css

como dibujar varios cuadrados, mi estructura de html es: creo que dibuja pero quiero espaciarlos 1px, **y quiero dibujar mas cajitas arriba**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
.cajas {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  padding-right: 3px;
  background-color: red;
}

.cajitas {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="cajitas">
  <div class="cajas">

  </div>
  <div class="cajas">

  </div>
  <div class="cajas">

  </div>
  <div class="cajas">

  </div>
  <div class="cajas">

  </div>
  <div class="cajas">

  </div>
  <div class="cajas">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se si te he entendido bien... pero creo que lo haz tenido bastante cerca:

```css
.cajas {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 1px;
}

.cajitas {
  display: flex;
  
  /* Por si quieres cambiar las alineación */
  
  /* justify-content: flex-start | flex-end | center | space-between | space-around | space-evenly; */
}
```

```html
<div class="cajitas">
  <div class="cajas"></div>
  <div class="cajas"></div>
  <div class="cajas"></div>
  <div class="cajas"></div>
  <div class="cajas"></div>
</div>
<div class="cajitas">
  <div class="cajas"></div>
  <div class="cajas"></div>
  <div class="cajas"></div>
  <div class="cajas"></div>
  <div class="cajas"></div>
  <div class="cajas"></div>
</div>

<div class="cajitas">
  <div class="cajas"></div>
  <div class="cajas"></div>
  <div class="cajas"></div>
  <div class="cajas"></div>
  <div class="cajas"></div>
  <div class="cajas"></div>
  <div class="cajas"></div>
  <div class="cajas"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: como puedo disminuir 1 o 2 por cada fila?, es decir la fila de arriba tendria digamos 5, la del medio 6 y la de abajo tenga 8

Comment: @hubman - Y debería ser centrado al resto de las cajas? Como una pirámide?

Comment: no quiero que se paresca a una piramide

Comment: @hubman - Si no quieres que parezca a una pirámide... elimina simplemente las cajas deseadas

Answer (score 1):

```
.cajitas {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.cajas {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 1px;
}
```

Las cajas que estén dentro del div con clase "cajitas" estarán alineadas al centro vertical y horizontalmente, tenga la resolución que tenga el navegador